# Linked List is Replacing

Tags: c++, csv, linked-list

I am using C++ linked list and visual Studio to create form and save it into a csv file. The problem its occuring for me here is that it works fine and everytime i Add, it adds perfectly. BUT after I close the program and reopen, and add again, the whole data is the csv file clears out and adds a new one.

So basically when i rerun the program, it does not add the product, but delete all and then add.

```
void BootLinkedList::bootSave()
    {
        ofstream infile;
        infile.open("footwear2.csv");
        Boots *node = head;
        while (node != NULL)
        {
            infile << node->getCode() << "," << node->getBrand() << "," << node->getColor() << "," << node->getSize() << "," << node->getPrice() << "," << node->getType() << "," << node->getSoleStyle() << "," << node->getBootType() << "," << node->getBootStyle() << "," << "-" << endl;
            node = node->getNext();
        }

        infile.close();
    }
```

Comment: you need to open file in different mode

Comment: You might read in the nodes from the file when starting up so you don't start with an empty list each time, because that is in many cases the main reason for persistency.

Comment: Naming a file you write to "infile" seems unnecessarily confusing. (You also don't need to explicitly close the stream - `ofstream`'s destructor handles that correctly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 infile.open("footwear2.csv");
```

to

```
 infile.open("footwear2.csv", ios::out | ios::app);
```

See detains in [references](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/)